# Optimize query to information_schema

Tags: mysql

A site I run has a large number of searches that get performed.  These searches are non-trivial and have multiple pieces of data that need to get joined to the results.

My solution was to store search results in two tables: searches and searchresults

Searches contains the metadata of the search

Searchresults contains two columns idsearch, iddata and is a memory table

In order to prevent memory overflow of searchresults, we periodically prune this table and flush stale data.  As far as I understand, memory tables have table level locking, so during the pruning, the searchresults table gets blocked and causes site performance to degrade.

The solution was to create a new table for each search and then drop this searchresults_xxxx table when the search is stale.

I'm doing this by first deleting old stale entries in the searches table.  Then executing the following:

```
select table_name
from information_schema.tables
where 
    table_schema = 'mysite_datawarehouse' 
    and table_name not in (select concat('searchresults_', idsearch) from searches);
```

There are often several thousands of matches that hit, resulting in an average query time of ~30 seconds or so.  During this time, performance again degrades and I'm back to square one. Is there a better way to write this?  Or perhaps a better way to architect this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you define periodically? If you mean every night at 2am does it matter that it takes 30 seconds? If you're doing it during the day can you only do it at night? To improve your query you could turn it into a join. `not in` can be nasty if your tables get any size to them.

Comment: Every 10 minutes searches are invalid.  Searches usually has a ~5k rows before it gets cleaned.  Each search usually has between ~1k and ~20k results stored in searchresults.  So purging old results gets fairly important.

Answer (score 0):

I've just asked and resolved a related Q: [Slow query on information_schema.tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290433/slow-query-on-information-schema-tables).  The issue that you have here is that the query will enumerate all tables in your data directory by doing directory scan for the *.FRM files.  It may also open every FRM file and read its header.   This is going to be slow.

My Q is why query the information schema at all?  I assume that you trust the contents of searches.  Why not just include a creation timestamp field in the **searches** and select all table names where the creation rimestamp is older than a certain age.  If it then straight forward doing a loop doing a drop table if exists and even moving this cleanup process into a stored procedure.  Doing the main query on the information schema adds nothing and slows the prune process down.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you original query

```
select table_name
from information_schema.tables
where 
    table_schema = 'mysite_datawarehouse' 
    and table_name not in
    (select concat('searchresults_', idsearch) from searches);
```

I would easily expect it to be slow if there are a bunch of InnoDB tables to navigate through

Try refactoring query query to perform a LEFT JOIN as follows:

```
select A.table_name
from (select concat('searchresults_', idsearch) table_name from searches) A
LEFT JOIN
(select table_name FROM information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'mysite_datawarehouse') B
USING (table_name)
WHERE B.table_name IS NULL;
```