# Slow query on information_schema.tables

Tags: mysql, performance

I run a set of self-developed applications on a typical shared hosting service offering.  I moved from a static configured table list of allowed tables to one based on a list of tables bases on a prefix from the D/B metadata.  When I did promote this version to the public service, my per-request latency increased by an average **2.3–2.4 secs**. Some instrumentation revealed that this was entirely down to one SQL query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<DBname>'
AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '<TablePrefix>%';
```

I used this because I wanted to explicitly name the column in the result set.  However, coding around this with an alternate query adds an extra line of code which ran in **<2 mSec**:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '<TablePrefix>%';
```

My service provider uses Enterprise MySql 5.0.92-50 so I can't do any profiling.  This is a scaling issue as it doesn't occur on my dev environment and test VM where I can profile. They support thousands of users so the live schema will be extremely large, but even so connection and most queries only take milliseconds.

Does anyone know why querying the memory-based information_schema on a large multi-user system would take so long?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information schema is not optimized, there are no indexes, just tables with metadata, and usually, when you run SELECT from the schema, it opens and reads files.

Have a look at this article - [Optimizing INFORMATION_SCHEMA Queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema-optimization.html); in some cases it will help you.

Comment: Devant, thanks for this.  I use a constant DB name and constant pattern for my 'prefix_%' like clause on the tablename, so the query is near optimum.  However, I also checked back to the 5.0 and 5.1 versions of this section.  The 5.1 version clarifies that these performance optimisations were only introduced 5.1.21, and therefore I assume that the don't apply to 5.0.92. So at best the MySQL engine is doing a database directory scan to return this information.  The "ENGINE=MEMORY" clause in the this table is misleading.  What I still can't figure is why the show version is so fast.

Comment: I did an strace of the mysqld for the **SHOW TABLES LIKE** statement and this does an **openat()** of the DB dir, get the dir entries and then opens each FRM file of the tables matching the pattern, but these are all in the VFAT cache on my system so this takes a few millisecond.  The SELECT statement is event faster in that this does the same **openat()+getents()** but doesn't open the FRM files.  So I guess that this is a feature of my hosting provider still using MySQL 5.0

Comment: Your ans pushed my in the right direction and helped me answer the Q myself.  Its a pity that I've trashed my old Ubuntu 8.04 VM so I don't have a LAMP stack running MySQL 5.0 that I can strace, but I am happy that the unoptimized aspect of the I_S queries and a complete scan is the root problem.

Answer (score 10):

For those who may want a hack with a minor drawback:

What it does is it disable some stats that get updated if you query the schema, more information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata

You only need to make a change to a setting:

```
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
```

You can do this in the config file or dynamically:

```
mysql> set global innodb_stats_on_metadata=0;
```

Comment: Thanks foe this feedbacks, but this was a MySQL over MyISAM issue and I ended up stracing the MYSQL daemon for 5.0 and 5,1 to get to the bottom of it.  Your fix won't help the OQ.

Comment: Note the innodb_stats_on_metadata setting is not available in MySQL 5.0