# \Zend\Db\Metadata\Metadata slow on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

Retrieving metadata from a table (`getConstraints()` or `getColumns()`) using Zend Framework 2 with MySQL is terribly slow. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Mysql is terribly slow retrieving data from information schema. One solution is disabling stats on metadata by modifyng 'my.cfn'

```
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
```

You can do this in the config file or dynamically:

```
mysql> set global innodb_stats_on_metadata=0;
```

[Slow query on information_schema.tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290433/slow-query-on-information-schema-tables)